# Python UDF in Pig

Tags: python, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

Whenever I try to import external packages of python in a pig udf, it shows the following error

> Python Error. Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "pythonudf.py", line 5, in 
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>   ImportError: No module named bs4

I've tried including the library path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')
```

And set

```
export JYTHONPATH=$JYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

But it is still showing the same error. 
What else can I do?
The script isn't running in local or mapreduce mode.

PS: Other functions which do not import external packages are running perfectly.

EDIT:
The packages in the python code are installed.

Comment: try to install beautifulsoup `pip install bs4`

Comment: Its installed. The python script in running in python separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-embedded` option when executing pig with python udf importing packages.[Reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4353)

```
pig -embedded jython pythonudf.py
```